# Boolean values supported by spark-csv by databricks

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am unable to load the csv with 't' and 'f' value for the boolean column inside the DataFrame using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/) by Databricks.

There is already an open [issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/104) related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about if you read that column as a string then use some of `sql.functions` to replace its values for true or false?

Comment: we are directly loading the schema from redshift table and using that schema we are loading csv. And this needs to done for multiple tables.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is that until they fix the bug. Fist replace all columns `BooleanType` for `StringType`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try your  solution by changing the datatype inside the DataFrame.